# How to refer to a certain TextEdit in a specific Android Fragment?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I'm developing an Android app and for this I want to have a fragment with which the user can insert an amount. The fragment has a couple methods, like inserting the correct currency symbol on the basis of the country.

I now want the user to be able to insert several amounts on the same screen. As far as I understand I can reuse one fragment several times for this. Every time the fragment is used in the main xml it gets an id, and every fragment contains a couple EditTexts which each have an id as well.

I now wonder how I can get the value of a certain EditText within a certain fragment. So lets say I want to get the result of `edit_text_2` from within `fragment_3` (both are their respective id's). How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get result from fragment via callback. Please check following documents:

```
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Check these links out:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Fragments are made to be self-contained, so that they don't know what is outside of them, and their containing activity doesn't necessarily know what is inside of them. You need to create an interface for the `Activity` to call to get the reference to your `EditText`.